# F2FS issue - unsuccessful remove, lost access to files

Tags: linux, filesystems, linux-kernel, filesystem-corruption

While removing unnecessary files I bumped into an error. with

```
fsck.f2fs /dev/sda4 -t
```

I can see

```
|   |   |-- Die Ärzte - Manchmal haben Frauen <ino = 0xc11874>, <encrypted (0)>
|   |   |   |-- Die Ärzte - Manchmal haben Frauen [CO].jpg <ino = 0xc0d304>, <encrypted (0)>
|   |   |   |-- Die Ärzte - Manchmal haben Frauen.txt <ino = 0xc0d4cd>, <encrypted (0)>
|   |   |   |-- High.sco <ino = 0xc0d2d7>, <encrypted (0)>
|   |   |   |-- Die Ärzte - Manchmal haben Frauen.mp3 <ino = 0xc115da>, <encrypted (0)>
|   |   |   |-- Die Ärzte - Manchmal haben Frauen [BG].jpg <ino = 0xc0d2de>, <encrypted (0)>
```

but I lost access to those files. I'm unable to delete them or even read them. **Is there any API in f2fs to force removal of some inodes?** I'm a bit afraid to touch the guts of the kernel driver...

```
ls -lR result:

ls: cannot access Die Ärzte - Manchmal haben Frauen: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Die Ärzte - Westerland: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Die Ärzte - Zu Spät: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Disney - Gummibären: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Kikki, Bettan och Lotta - Vem È Dé Du Vill Ha: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access No Doubt - It´s my life: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Queen - Don´t stop me now: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Roger Pontare - När Vindarna Viskar Mitt Namn: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Die Ärzte - Schrei nach Liebe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Jan Johansen - Se På Mig: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Linda Bengtzing - Jag Ljuger Så Bra: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Magnus Uggla - För Kung Och Fosterland: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Markoolio Och Linda Bengtzing - Värsta Schlagern: No such file or directory
ls: cannot access Markus - Ich will Spaß: No such file or directory
total 0
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Die Ärzte - Manchmal haben Frauen
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Die Ärzte - Schrei nach Liebe
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Die Ärzte - Westerland
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Die Ärzte - Zu Spät
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Disney - Gummibären
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Jan Johansen - Se På Mig
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Kikki, Bettan och Lotta - Vem È Dé Du Vill Ha
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Linda Bengtzing - Jag Ljuger Så Bra
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Magnus Uggla - För Kung Och Fosterland
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Markoolio Och Linda Bengtzing - Värsta Schlagern
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Markus - Ich will Spaß
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? No Doubt - It´s my life
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Queen - Don´t stop me now
d????????? ? ? ? ?            ? Roger Pontare - När Vindarna Viskar Mitt Namn
ls: cannot open directory ./Die Ärzte - Manchmal haben Frauen: No such file or directory
ls: cannot open directory ./Die Ärzte - Schrei nach Liebe: No such file or directory
ls: cannot open directory ./Die Ärzte - Westerland: No such file or directory
ls: cannot open directory ./Die Ärzte - Zu Spät: No such file or directory
ls: cannot open directory ./Disney - Gummibären: No such file or directory
ls: cannot open directory ./Jan Johansen - Se På Mig: No such file or directory
ls: cannot open directory ./Kikki, Bettan och Lotta - Vem È Dé Du Vill Ha: No such file or directory
ls: cannot open directory ./Linda Bengtzing - Jag Ljuger Så Bra: No such file or directory
ls: cannot open directory ./Magnus Uggla - För Kung Och Fosterland: No such file or directory
ls: cannot open directory ./Markoolio Och Linda Bengtzing - Värsta Schlagern: No such file or directory
ls: cannot open directory ./Markus - Ich will Spaß: No such file or directory
ls: cannot open directory ./No Doubt - It´s my life: No such file or directory
ls: cannot open directory ./Queen - Don´t stop me now: No such file or directory
ls: cannot open directory ./Roger Pontare - När Vindarna Viskar Mitt Namn: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0):

What I did was to make the file real first then delete it after.

```
echo x > 'Die Ärzte - Schrei nach Liebe'
rm 'Die Ärzte - Schrei nach Liebe'
```

Comment: unfortunately, this does not help in my case. After those files are created, I have two seemingly same instances of every of these files. I can only delete one of each, thus getting back to the former issue.

Comment: I had the two same files too. But it deleted both for me.

Comment: I think the difference between yours and mine were yours are "d" directories whereas mine were "l" links.